# qt app crash on start after adding a library

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm currently working on a QT application, targeting windows platform.

After compiling and installing ITPP (it++ library) on my system, I've tried to add it to this project, but after linking .lib and adding header files, when I try to include and use it, application crashes on start without any output!

What I get in application output:

```
AppName.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

In .pro file: (.lib and header folders are in root directory)

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -litpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
```

The code which causes the crash:

```
#include <itpp/itcomm.h>

using namespace itpp;
using namespace std;

... (sample from test files)
```

Comment: Most likely the dlls are not found when you run your application. Did you added their path into system path? Or copied those into the same folder as your exe?

Comment: The error is about missing dlls 0xc0000135. It's in this list: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) ***{Unable To Locate Component} This application has failed to start because %hs was not found. Reinstalling the application might fix this problem.***

Comment: If you start calc in programmer mode and paste `-1073741515` you get `0xc0000135` in the lower 32 bits. Just wanted to mention how I got that value..

Comment: @Zlatomir Thanks, The problem resolved after copying .dll next to .exe file. It was in the system32 folder but wasn't working! Maybe you can post an answer so I can choose it as the right answer.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. You were right. Maybe you can post an answer so I can choose it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

The error code you get, `-1073741515`, is in hex `0xc0000135`. According to the Microsoft documentation for status [codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55), there is a missing `dll`:

> STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND {Unable To Locate Component} This application has failed to start because %hs was not found. Reinstalling the application might fix this problem.

### Solution

Copy the dependent `dll`s to a folder of the `PATH` environment variable or to the location of your executable.